# How does custom exception handling works, Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Custom Exception Class,

```
class CustomFileExcetion(FileNotFoundError):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Custom Exception Used,

```
def oppen_file(file_path):
    try:
        open('xyx')
    except CustomFileExcetion as exp:
        print(exp)

    print('100')
```

I am trying to make custom exception, but thing is that it does not capture
my exception, it throws exception

Exception Raised,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mario/file_exception.py", line 14, in <module>
    open('xyx')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xyx'
```

But when replace `CustomFileException` with `FileNotFoundError` or `Exception`, it captures exception and output as

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xyx'
100
```

Comment: The built-in `open` function does not `raise` your custom exception. You have to raise a custom exception on your own.

Answer (score 3):

`open` raises a `FileNotFoundError`. That's what it does, you can't change that.

You're extending `FileNotFoundError` with a new subclass. That subclass is a *more specific* class than `FileNotFoundError`. If you're catching that more specific subclass, that won't match the more generic parent class. I.e., `except CustomFileExcetion` [sic] will not catch `FileNotFoundError`.

If you want to use your own custom exceptions, you'll have to raise them yourself. E.g. you could make your `oppen_file` [sic] function to use that custom exception:

```
def oppen_file(file_path):
    try:
        open(file_path)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        raise CustomFileExcetion from e
```

Now every caller of `oppen_file` can expect to use `CustomFileExcetion`:

```
try:
    oppen_file(path)
except CustomFileExcetion:
    ...
```

Usually you would implement your own custom exceptions for your own business logic; i.e. there's little sense in duplicating/extending/customising a `FileNotFoundError`, but you may implement entirely new exceptions which are relevant to your specific program, like `UserPermissionsInsufficientError` or `CoordinatesOutOfBoundsError` or whatever makes sense in your specific domain.

Comment: That's mean I cannot extend the inbuilt Exception for getting this type of exception, I am also trying it with `1/0` with custom Exception but it only works with `ZeroDivisionError`, and it's parent Exceptions not with custom.

Comment: Yes, again, it's hardcoded what Python code will raise what exception. In the example above, you can't do anything to make `oppen_file` raise anything other than a `CustomFileExcetion`. You can extend exception classes all you want for whatever purpose you want, but you can't make existing code raise any other exception than it does. And that's a positive thing, since it would otherwise be unpredictable what exceptions a function will raise. Exceptions are part of the API/signature, so it's good that that's unchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomFileExcetion` is a sub-class  to the `FileNotFoundError`; your code throws the latter which can only be caught by the same class or its parent-class or super-class. You cannot catch an exception by its sub-class.

To achieve your purpose, you need to raise your custom-exception and then catch it.
Something like @deceze wrote.